# Jetpack-compose Scaffold scroll bottomBar when keyboard opens

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

I'm developing a small jetpack-compose demo chat app. So I need a bar at the bottom with a TextField and a Button to send, just like in WhatsApp.... I figured it would be best to use a Scaffold with a bottomBar.

The problem now is, the bottomBar, is hidden behind the keyboard, when the keyboard opens. Any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably should try to push your bottomBar by keyboard's inset, using Accompanist lib.
https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/